# Given $a^2+b^2=2$ prove $a+b\le2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

1. Given $a^2+b^2=2$ prove $a+b\le2$
2. Given $a+b=2$ prove $a^4+b^4\ge2$

I was trying to prove these using the fact that we know $a^2+b^2\ge2ab$ but not sure where to start.

Comment: For 1. from your idea $$ab\le 1\implies 2ab\le 2\implies a^2+b^2+2ab\le 4\implies |a+b|\le 2\implies a+b\le2$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using AM-GM inequality:

$\displaystyle\frac{a^2+b^2}{2} \geq \sqrt {a^2b^2}$

$\displaystyle{a^2+b^2}\geq  {2ab}$

We know :

$\displaystyle\ a^2+b^2=2$

Equating the above equations, we get

$\displaystyle\ 2ab \leq 2$

Adding two equations above we get:

$\displaystyle\ a^2+b^2+2ab \leq 4$

Taking Square Roots both the sides:

$\displaystyle\ -2\leq a+b\leq 2$

Therefore,

$\displaystyle\ a+b\leq 2$

---

$\displaystyle\frac{a^4+b^4}{2}\geq \sqrt {a^4b^4}$

$\displaystyle{a^4+b^4}\geq 2a^2b^2$

$\displaystyle{a^4+b^4}\geq 2(ab)^2$

We can also write it as:

$\displaystyle{a^4+b^4}\geq 2$

Because

$\ 2\leq 2(ab)^2$

Comment: is there a way to prove the second claim using AM-GM inequality as well?

Comment: @Michelle Stasso, even the second claim can be solved using AM-GM inequality.Try solving it, if not feel free to ask me

Comment: I am trying to manipulate the inequality to use the given but I am not ending up with the fourth root of a+b

Comment: @MichelleStasso i hope its clear now

Answer (score 5):

Courtsey : $\rightarrow$ Cauchy Schwarz

$$(a+b)^2\le(1+1)(a^2+b^2)\\\implies a+b\le |a+b|\le 2$$

$$$$Now by the fact that $a+b=2$ and $a^2+b^2\ge 2ab$, we deduce that $2(a^2+b^2)\ge 4\implies a^2+b^2\ge 2$ $$(a^2+b^2)^2\leq2(a^4+b^4)\\ \implies a^4+b^4\ge 2$$

BINGO!

Comment: Aren't (1) and (2) separate problems?

Comment: But how does then it follow that $a^4+b^4\ge 2$? From Cauchy-Schwarz it follows that $(a^2+b^2)^2\le 2(a^4+b^4)$ as you have written. But it may happen that $4>2(a^4+b^4)\ge (a^2+b^2)^2$. How do you argue that it can't happen?

Comment: To be complete you need to mention the case $a+b \leq 0$.

Comment: @S.Das There you finally go!

Comment: @abnry AM I fine now?

Comment: I was thinking of the square root in the first part. I'd change it to $a+b \leq |a+b| \leq 2$.

Comment: @abnry Complied with your argument!

Comment: Great! Thanks for considering my small suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

By $1$-d version of polarization identity $(a+b)^2 + (a-b)^2 = 2(a^2+b^2)$,

1. If $a^2 + b^2 = 2$, then
   $$(a+b)^2 = 2(a^2+b^2) - (a-b)^2\le 2(a^2+b^2) = 4 \quad\implies\quad a+b \le |a+b| \le 2$$
2. If $a + b = 2$, then
   $$
   8(a^4+b^4) = 4((a^2+b^2)^2 + (a^2-b^2)^2)\\
   \ge 4(a^2+b^2)^2 = (2(a^2+b^2))^2 = ((a+b)^2 + (a-b)^2)^2\\
   \ge (a+b)^4 = 16\\
   {\large\Downarrow}\\
   a^4+b^4 \ge 2
   $$

Answer (score 0):

Let $$a = \sqrt2 \sin(t), \qquad b = \sqrt2 \cos(t)$$
Now we need to show that $$\sin(t) + \cos(t) \le \sqrt2$$ which is equivalent to showing that $$\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\ sin(t) + \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\cos(t) \le 1$$ but $$\frac{1}{\sqrt2}\ sin(t) + \frac{1}{\sqrt2}\cos(t) = sin(\frac{\pi}{4} + t) \le 1$$